# Replace numbers with certain corresponding strings programatically

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large amount of numbers in an Excel spreadsheet that I want to replace with text. It looks something like this:

```
33
33
33
33
22
21
22
29
49
95
43
23
45
12
11
22
```

I want all of the `33`'s to be replaced with "Clothing", all of the `22`'s to be replaced with "House", etc. I have to do this on a day-to-day basis, so I don't want to use the lookup and replace button and go through 43 numbers, replacing them with custom strings.

How can this be automated?

Comment: Have you considered using vba http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/vba-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-text-string-in/7fe3bc1b-81fc-446c-ac98-b76e69464c13?msgId=4cdd05d6-465b-450a-a071-55dffd9849ab

Comment: no i have not tried that, i don't know what that is but i will try it now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vba macro (Developer tab -> Visual Basic -> Sheet1(your sheet where you need replacements) and paste following code to visual basic editor, then click "execute")

```
Sub ReplaceNumbers()
With Range("A1:A20000")
    .Replace "33", "Clothing", xlWhole, , True
    .Replace "22", "House", xlWhole, , True
End With
End Sub
```

That is the most hard-coded solution, i'm sure there is a lot of things that can be improved, thought it works.
If you want to add replacement rule, just add line

```
.Replace "Number-to-replace", "Replacement", xlWhole, , True
```

Comment: Why `xlPart` instead of `xlWhole`?

Comment: Seems to be my mistake. Updated post.

Comment: I dont have a Developer tab i have a Macro button but i don't see anything about Visual Basic

Comment: i figured it out and it worked thank you very much for your help!